# Enum return type not working C [Error C2440]

Tags: c++, enums, return

Consider the following:

```
class Specimen
{
public:
enum Gender getGender();
private:
enum Gender { MALE=1, FEMALE=2, ALIEN=3, HYBRID=4};
}
```

This part as well:

```
Gender gender;
```

under private

```
enum Gender Specimen::getGender()
{
    return gender;
}
```

that's a member function
the compiler says
"error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'Specimen::gender' to 'Gender'
I also tried removing the "enums" from the function def and the function prototype

I am not sure what I need to fix

Answer (score 3):

`Specimen` is not in scope and so you have to qualify it:

```
enum Specimen::Gender Specimen::getGender()
{
    return gender;
}
```

This works too in C++11:

```
auto Specimen::getGender() -> Gender
{
    return gender;
}
```

Comment: does the function prototype stay the same?

Comment: @MuadDib42 Yes. `Gender` is in-scope when used inside the class body.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how and where `gender` and `getGender()` are declared/defined, but the following compiles:

```
class Specimen
{
public:
    enum Gender { MALE=1, FEMALE=2, ALIEN=3, HYBRID=4};
    Gender getGender();
private:
    Gender gender;
};

Specimen::Gender Specimen::getGender()
{
    return gender;
}

int main() {}
```

See it work [here](http://ideone.com/WbwmAu).

Note that `enum Gender` was moved above the `getGender()` declaration, and `Gender` is qualified as `Specimen::Gender` in the `getGender()` definition.